# How to load google sheets URL CSV into global environment using fread

Tags: dataframe, fread, shinyapps

Running my shiny app after using R console to load google sheets CSV, then loading using fread, my app loads the CSV locally.  When I do not load the data set using R Console, the CSV does not populate.  How do I load google sheets CSV into the global environment using fread?

Have tried options(datatable.fread.datatable=false) but it did not work

```
csvBase1 <- fread('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSfiMFwfucJl7CXEufaGcZjRS8B6cRZgsHngkqx5moe5edBGtyCc-cQW4Oe_7kdDC0zcdXRBAbWA0GA/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv')
```

Expecting to be able to figure out how to load the data in the global environment with fread to populate DT (data tables) without having to manually (local) load data frame using R console, which will not work for ShinyApps.io deployment.